# Coating galvanized cable so it's rust-proof and sun-proof?

Tags: roof, paint, waterproofing, cables, rust-proofing

The cable's galvanized, so what coating can I add to the cable so it's rust proof and sun-proof? It should be clear and barely visible. And it shouldn't be too expensive.

We live in the tropics, so we get 95° weather, tons of sun, and we're very close to the ocean. It can't crack, turn yellow, etc.

Thanks.

Comment: I guess that just using stainless steel cable is out of the question?  Because that's really the best answer.

Comment: If it's galvanized, then it's already rust-proof. But since you're asking about making it sun-proof then I'm not sure we're talking about the same thing... What do you mean by "galvanized", since to me that means hot-dipped or electroplated with zinc?

Comment: Clear lacquer, enamel, or acrylic paint?

Comment: NASA wrote the book on protecting metals in tropical oceanfront environments.  Http://corrosion.ksc.nasa.gov

Comment: @JPhi1618: I'd gladly buy stainless steel if it's 1/4" x 250' for $65 plus free shipping outside of the US.

Comment: @brhans: The description says it's galvanized, but several reviewers have said that it tends to rust after a few years. I think galvanized's more rust-resistant than rust-proof.

Comment: No ferrous thing is completely rust-proof. It'll require regular maintenance. I'd use it until it starts showing rust, then clean it and apply a zinc spray paint.

Comment: You don't say what kind of use or abuse the cable will be subject to.  If you feel the need to coat the cable, you can do that, but the coating has to stand up to the cable's usage (flexing, abrasion, compression, etc. in addition to the environment).  Also, you can coat the cable, but the weak link will be any uncoated spot, like at a fastener.  They make jacketed cable, but the jacket typically won't last long in intense sunlight or hold up at fastening points.  Typical "finishes", like paint or lacquer, are brittle.  (cont'd)

Comment: If it's strictly for appearance in fixed areas, you could thin some clear silicone caulk to paint consistency and brush it on, but it will not be very wear resistant if the cable with be subject to handling or abrasion.

Answer (score 3):

If you are too cheap (re: specific price presumably that of the galvanized cable) to do it right, don't expect miracles - being cheap is expensive (every time you have to replace the cheap item, + the cost of each failure.)

Galvanized is already sun-proof, the only way to make it not sun-proof is to coat it with plastic that's damaged by the sun.

It's also rust-resistant, but CHEAP cable will be minimally coated with zinc and thus the sacrificial protection of the zinc will soon wear through, exposing steel, and rusting. High-quality galvanized cable will have a thicker coating and a higher initial price tag.

That or a proper grade of stainless (be sure to factor in the salt exposure for "near ocean" in picking an alloy) will be less costly in the long run than cheap galvanized cable, assuming the rest of the system involving the cable will survive a hurricane. If not, you might just as well use cheap cable and replace it when you replace/rebuild everything after a hurricane.

Comment: The problem is that this information is not included in the item's description. How do I know how much zinc it has?